# Why does iTerm2 print out 1 at start?

Tags: zsh, iterm2

my problem is that iTerm print out the 1 value on my zsh when i open it i can't figure it out why. I've checked the advanced setting in my profile configuration but it seems that nothing is added there.

can you help me to understand where the 1 come from?

thank you.

Comment: Is "1" also printed out in zsh when you open it in terminal?

Comment: Does it print the "1" before or after the first prompt? As I understand you checked the iTerm2 configuration, but did you check your zsh configuration (`~/.zshrc`)?

Comment: To narrow down, start in an existing terminal `zsh` and `zsh -f`. If the former does, but the latter does not print a "1", the fault is definitively in your config.

Comment: I have the same problem, but with bash. `bash` and `bash -f` does not print anything.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled on this problem and just figured it out.

I had `iTerm2.app > Preferences > Profiles > Window > Space` set to `Space 1`. Setting it back to `Current Space` solved this problem for me.

Comment: Oh my god! You saved me from deleting my entire zsh config and possibly a system reset. it was driving me crazy.